# How do I install/use GridWorld?

Tags: java, eclipse, gridworld

I have tried everything and I just can't get GridWorld to work (link: http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/public/courses/teachers_corner/151155.html).

I am using Eclipse (but I have tried NetBeans and Geany and they didn't do it).

I searched online and found out how you're supposed to do it. I followed the instructions: I clicked Next in the Create Project window after entering the name of the project, linked GridWorld as an external JAR in the Libraries tab, and clicked Finish.

But then, Eclipse didn't create the project properly. It made one ".settings" folder with a "org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs" file inside, two empty folders: "bin" and "src", and two other files: ".classpath" and ".project." And it didn't open the project.

Can you help me? Maybe the files are actually usable? If so, then please tell me how to open them. Otherwise, can you recommend another IDE or tell me what to do? BTW, I need to install GridWorld to continue in *Think Java*.

My machine is an Acer Aspire R 14 with Windows 10 Home, an Intel core i5 processor, and 8GB of RAM.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what it's supposed to do, and the project that was created was Open in Eclipse parlance. What were you *expecting* instead?

Comment: I was expecting it to create a .java file or something that would actually open, and for it to open automatically.